# Reestablishing a clicked button style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help: I made three buttons, once I click one of them, its style should be changed through Javascript. That is working. But something else should happen: once I click the button again, the old style shoud be recovered. Take a look at the code:

```
function changeStyleOne(){
if(this.style.background != 'rgba(207,207,207,.8)'){
    this.style.background = 'rgba(207,207,207,.8)';
    this.style.boxShadow = '0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset';
    this.style.borderLeft = '0';
    this.style.width = '99px';

    button2.style.background = '-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #B9B9B9 0%, white 90%)';
    button2.style.width = '98px';
    button2.style.borderLeft = '1px solid white';
    button2.style.boxShadow = '';
    button3.style.background = '-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #B9B9B9 0%, white 90%)';
    button3.style.width = '98px';
    button3.style.borderLeft = '1px solid white';
    button3.style.boxShadow = '';

displayContent1();

}else{
    this.style.background = '-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #B9B9B9 0%, white 90%)';
    this.style.boxShadow = '';
    this.style.borderLeft = '1px solid white';
    this.style.width = '98px';
}
```

}

That is not working: when I click the button again, it doesn't recover the old style. Do you know why?

Comment: Using class, and toggle between classnames would be the best solution.

Comment: Sometimes browsers have trouble working with `rgb(x, x, x)`, same goes for rgba. I did the same today - worked fine in Chrome but Firefox said no. Working with classes would indeed be better.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you say `'rgba(207,207,207,.8)'`, the EMCA Script is parsing this string, interpreting it as an `rbga` spec and then parseing each value.  The first three `207` values are stored as integral values, but the last .8 is stored as floating point.  So when you later ask for `this.style.background`, it may come back as `'rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.8)'` or some such (maybe on the right Pentium, it would come up `0.799999999`).  Thus, don't expect it to return literally (character by character) what you passed it.  The class is not treated this way since it is a string identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example,

http://jsfiddle.net/LT4sQ/

```
.class1 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #B9B9B9 0%, white 90%);
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    width: 98px;
}
.class2 {
    background: rgba(207, 207, 207, .8);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 99px;
}

function changeStyleOne(e) {
    e.className = (e.className == "class1") ? "class2" : "class1";
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, putting Javascript inline on the HTML is a bad practice. [More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup) on that.

Comment: That works as well, although I didn't understand the syntax, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example you can learn from:

HTML:

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

CSS:

```
.styled {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('styled');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rCWsJ/)

Comment: That works, thank you very much. I don't know jQuery, because I am a completely newbie on Web Development. But again, thank you, I will try to adapt that!